# HTTP Security Header Not Detected in JBoss EAP 6.4

Tags: security, jboss, jboss6.x

We need to fix a vulnerability in **JBoss EAP 6.4** which is related to **HTTP Security Header Not Detected** (QID 11827).

This vulnerability is reported on the application server layer, and not on IHS.
All the suggestions online are for JBoss EAP 7.x (undertow subsystem), and not applicable to JBoss EAP 6.4 (web subsystem).

I have tried to add filters under the WEB subsystem, in the standalone.xml, but it has not worked. Probably I am not using the correct format/syntax.

Please advise.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The aforementioned QID (11827) is detected when the following HTTP Headers are missing:

- X-Frame-Options
- X-XSS-Protection HTTP
- X-Content-Type-Options
- Strict-Transport-Security

A nice and easy way to set theses headers is by implementing a **custom filter**. Please note that this is for a specific web application !

If you want to set these http headers **globally**, then you must implement a **custom valve**!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have not able to add custom filters in the standalone.xml. Looks like the syntax is incorrect, because of which JBoss doesn't restart. Will you be able to provide a sample custom filter for JBoss 6.4? That would be a great help.

Comment: You have to develop a custom filter and then you need to put this jar in web application's lib folder!